# Application Express PL SQL Group by Function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to use a group by to get a report that lists total sales per day. SO the desired output would look like this:

- Monday January 13, 2014     $550
- Tuesday January 14, 2014   $600

  Tuesday January 14, 2014   $600

etc.

When I use the following code:

```
SELECT
  tix.user_id,
  tix.timestamp,
  tix.event_id,
  tixp.Price AS "Total Sales"
FROM LS_tickets tix
LEFT OUTER JOIN LS_ticket_prices tixP
  ON tixP.event_ID = tix.event_ID
WHERE
  tix.event_id = 12181
```

The query returns a table but is not providing TOTALS by day. It provides each individual sale. SO I try and modify it as follows:

```
SELECT
  tix.user_id,
  tix.timestamp,
  tix.event_id,
  sum(tixp.Price AS "Total Sales")
FROM LS_tickets tix
LEFT OUTER JOIN LS_ticket_prices tixP
  ON tixP.event_ID = tix.event_ID
WHERE
  tix.event_id = 12181
GROUP BY tix.timestamp
```

I get the following error:

Query cannot be parsed, please check the syntax of your query. (ORA-00936: missing expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want total by day, then you need to group by the day.  Assuming that `timestamp` is a date data type:

```
SELECT trunc(tix.timestamp) as thedate,
       sum(tixp.Price) AS "Total Sales"
FROM LS_tickets tix LEFT OUTER JOIN
     LS_ticket_prices tixP
     ON tixP.event_ID = tix.event_ID
WHERE tix.event_id = 12181
GROUP BY trunc(tix.timestamp)
ORDER BY 1;
```

You can get the particular date format that you want using `to_char()`.  This format may work for you:

```
SELECT to_char(tix.timestamp, 'DY MM DD, YYYY') as thedate,
       sum(tixp.Price) AS "Total Sales"
FROM LS_tickets tix LEFT OUTER JOIN
     LS_ticket_prices tixP
     ON tixP.event_ID = tix.event_ID
WHERE tix.event_id = 12181
GROUP BY to_char(tix.timestamp, 'DY MM DD, YYYY') 
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: That helped but I am getting only one column with dollar value, no date column.

Comment: Actually the one column thing might have been a caching issue. I am however getting more total sales than I should.

Comment: I sorted out my join and resolved all the issues. Thank you very much for your guidance.